# Create a variable with my name. Then alert the string “hello from” plus the variable I created

Tags: javascript, html, alert, var

This is what i have so far but my var name is not appearing in the alert. Please help! I just need to add the variable Name to the current alert ".

HTML

```
<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Name" />
```

Script

```
function show_alert(name) 
{
    var name= "Joshua";
    alert("Hello from"'+ name');    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the alert to:

```
alert("Hello from" + name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, javacript variable doesn't wrapped inside the `'`

```
alert("Hello from "+ name);
```

instead of

```
 alert("Hello from"'+ name');
```

You code:

```
 function show_alert() 
  {     
    var name = document.getElementById('myname').value;
    alert("Hello from"+ name);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
     <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" value="Joshua" />
   <input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Name" />
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quote `

```
alert("Hello from" + name);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ecIMaYOP/4/)**